doSomethingIfCondition(). Is it good naming?
Suppose, I have some method that performs some job. In this example, it's going to be void, but it doesn't matter
public void doSomething() {
    // doing something
}

But then, let's imagine, I got my team mates complaining that my method, on occasion, doesn't actually do "something". It's because it includes some condition check. It could be a state check or input validation, but since my sample method doesn't take any arguments, let's assume it's the former
public void doSomething() {
    if (isCondition()) {
        /* 
           I guess I could ask a separate question 
           on whether doDoSomething() is good naming
        */
        doDoSomething()
    }
}

I have two options:

Document it
Incorporate that information in the method's name

I recall from Bob Martin's Clean Code that comments should always be seen as a failure — a failure to write code that explains itself. Obviously, I don't want to fail (I want to win, win, win). So I opt for the latter option
public void doSomethingIfCondition()

Then, another change. For whatever reason, I now have to check one extra condition. Since I don't want my method to lie (lying methods is a big no-no in clean code), I now have to change the method name again
public void doSomethingIfConditionOneOrConditionTwo()

That's ugly. But suppose I can somehow group those conditions semantically
public void doSomethingIfSuperCondition() {
    if (isSuperCondition()) {
        doDoSomething()
    }
}

private boolean isSuperCondition() {
    return isConditionOne() && isConditionTwo();
}

A spec overhaul. Now, neither "condition one" nor "condition two" matter one bit. It's "condition three" that really does. But here's the problem: my method became quite popular. There are a ton of clients, and it's not feasible to fix them. Or, perhaps, I don't even control all of my clients anymore. It became opensource or something. So the best I can come up with is this
/**
  @deprecated use {@link #doSomethingIfConditionThree} instead
*/
public void doSomethingIfSuperCondition() {
    if (isSuperCondition()) {
        doDoSomething()
    }
}

public void doSomethingIfConditionThree() {
    if (isConditionThree()) {
        doDoSomething()
    }
}

I can keep making this story up. The point is, I start to doubt that naming convention. I want to write clean, but trying to do so, in my fictional example, resulted in a pretty nonsensical code. I am not at all sure it's what Bob Martin intended
So, what do you think?

This could fall under "Tell Dont Ask". "DoSomething best way you see fit and dont bother me with condition details"

Duplicate of How to name a method which may or may not perform an action depending on a condition?

How do clients of your code know about the check? How do they know, that method results in noop?

How about ifConditionDoSomething()? Or better yet, if (condition()) doSomething(); This doesn't need to be a separate function; you're just bloating your code.

Can you give more concrete examples?

This question is similar to: How to name a method which may or may not perform an action depending on a condition?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Since you are such a fan of Bob Martin: have you ever seen him using examples with meaningless function names like doSomething? I think he always try to use much more realistic examples. I recommend you try to ask your questions in a similar manner, with realistic examples, then we can try to find a realistic answer.

@DocBrown I am AFK and don't remember exact identifiers, but here's an example. Once a GUI table is loaded, we often select the first row, table.selectRow(0). However, it throws when there's no data (because index 0 is now out of bounds). So we added another method, table.selectFirstRowIfExists(). The first method is used in a lot of places. Theoretically, correct program behavior may rely on that exception somewhere (even though it's wrong). So we chose to add a new method rather than include the check in the table.selectRow(..) itself

@SergeyZolotarev: such an example would have improved your question a lot - ideally, when it is not an invented example, but an issue you really have to solve. BTW, I think table.trySelectRow(0) (with a bool as return value) would be a better name. In case selectRow is a new method under your own control, you could also decide to design it directly not to throw when the selection isn't possible (but it depends heavily on the context if that's a suitable solution).

@DocBrown I didn't include any specifics on purpose. I didn't want the answers to be specific

@DocBrown booleans don't carry any information, unlike exceptions. That's why I'm skeptical about methods that return success flags. Besides, those flags may be misleading (e.g. true returned from set.add(e) doesn't actually guarantee the element was added). I may post a separate question on that

@SergeyZolotarev: there is no "perfect design", every decision is a tradeoff. And you are changing the goal, that's the problem with invented examples. You asked about "selectRow", and when I suggested you a viable (and not uncommon) solution, you evade it and ask about an "add" method. That's why we insist people should ask about their real-world issues, not about invented examples or meaningless method names.

@DocBrown I don't evade it, I just reject it. As for the original question, I did and do believe it could be answered generically. Besides, I obviously don't feel like posting a separate question for every method: "How do I name method X", "How do I name method Y"

@SergeyZolotarev: naming things is harder than you think. And I think the top answer you got is as generically as it can get,

Now that we know that a method deals with selection, we know that this question is an XY problem. It asks about selection method, while the problem is in getter method - getSelectedRow() should return a Maybe monad and not fail if no row is selected.

@Basilevs it's selectRow(..) itself that throws

@SergeyZolotarev in your question you state that it does not throw and clients complain.

@Basilevs I explicitly said in the post the example was fictional. But then Doc Brown made a request so I added a real example in the comments. I didn't want to be specific in the question itself

@SergeyZolotarev ok, irrespective of the question or comments, any two methods that belong to the same API should be mutually consistent. If setSelectedRow() does not throw or return a value, getSelectedRow() should return Maybe. If setSelectedRow() throws or returns a value, getSelectedRow() may throw as well.
getSelectedRow() should take into account whether client knows if a row is succesfully selected or not.

@Basilevs I'm not sure where you got getSelectedRow() from. I never introduced it anywhere. The point is setSelectedRow(0) throws if no rows are present (e.g. because there's no data in the db) so we added an extra method, selectFirstRowIfPresent() to avoid any client checks or try-catches. It's not the only example I could give. I certainly didn't want SE folks to focus on that particular case only

@SergeyZolotarev "team mates complaining" somehow discovered that method does not do something, they need for further interactions with the object. Which operations in particular does not matter, I've selected an obvious example.  Internal state of the object should not matter for a client of any operation, therefore, the state if the object is visible via those operations.

Code is full of conditionals. You can't specify the conditionals in all the symbol names!
If you find yourself tempted to include a condition in the name, it's possible your name is too low-level. There is probably a higher-level way of looking at the activity that would result in a name without the condition.
Instead of
void CreateDirectoryIfItDoesntExist(string path)

Try
void EnsureDirectoryExists(string path)

Or instead of
void StartIfReady();

Try
void TryStart();

Or instead of:
void UseRedIfEmergercy();

Try:
void ApplyPriorityColorLevel();    

Or instead of:
void WriteToLogIfDebugEnabled(string message);

Try:
void LogDebug(string message);


Good list. I might also add using return types and doc strings to communicate conditional details specifically. For example, instead of void startIfReady(), bool start() with a doc string, "returns true if successfully started, false otherwise."

Here's the appropriate prefix:
bob.jump();

What bob does when told to jump is up to bob. Bob could jump. Bob could ask you "how high?". Bob could ignore you completely. Jump isn't about what happens. Jump is a message you sent to bob. What bob does with it is up to bob.
Whenever you find yourself mutilating a name by filling it with implementation details understand you are harming abstraction. A name should tell me why to call it. Not what it does. Telling you what it does is not a names job. Name things that way and you wont have to rename them when you refactor.
Remember, a name is a comment. Comments should tell you why the code exists. Not what it does.

This answer has received a mixed reception and I can see it deserves some revision. Sorry it has taken so long. Family has its needs.
Let me ask this*:
ConfiguredWithNoFileSystem.EnsureDirectoryExists(somePath);
SystemThatNeverStops.TryStart();
BlackAndWhiteDisplay.ApplyPriorityColorLevel();

Isn't the Null Object Pattern something that could be useful here? Isn't silently doing nothing ok when that's what is really needed?
* I didn't include LogDebug(); in this list because silently doing nothing when so configured is something people have already accepted it doing. 
I absolutely agree with John Wu's point that a higher level of abstraction can free you of details that might clutter a name. He gives many good examples that communicate the expected post condition of the sunny day path. But permit me one nit pick. TryStart() is not a higher level of abstraction.
It is only announcing what you should already know. That this method might not do what you ask it to do depending on how it is configured. You should expect that even if it doesn't throw, even if it doesn't return an error, even if it doesn't report the issue thru some output port, it might do nothing, and silently ignore you. There is no method that could never end up needing to be configured to behave in this way.
The reason I feel that way is because the most recent knowledge always wins. Maybe in the past we were sure this will never be needed. Then time passes and it turns out we were wrong. Our job isn't to predict the future. It's to design systems that make it easy to deal with it.
I've taught this lesson for years, and I told a story that illustrates it in the middle of this somewhat old answer of mine.
The hard principle behind this idea is that reality doesn't care what you think. This is why we don't use composite natural keys in a live database. You may think combining phone number and social security will always ensure a unique id but all anyone has to do is add one more row and suddenly it doesn't work anymore. No, do that with dead data that you're trying to structure. And soon as you can make a unique key that isn't used for anything else besides being a unique key. That way reality can't mess with you.

Thank you. But then again, there may be good reasons to do something without a check. In that case, you'll probably have to include both do() and doIfCondition()

@SergeyZolotarev oh sure, ever rule has an exception. But ignoring the rule comes at a cost. Be sure you want to pay it rather than think of something better.

Jump is the worst example, because in natural language it may have a noop post-condition (jump in-place by default). I request an example with "jumpDown()" or "jumpOut()"

@Basilevs or it's the best example, because you should strive for things that take no parameters and return no value to have noop post conditions.

@Caleth noop post-condition for a method without return value makes no sense.

@Basilevs if it matters whether after doSomthing() something happened or not, then doSomething shouldn't be returning void. If it doesn't matter, then doSomthing() is fine

@Caleth What return value do you require from updateUI() method and why?  It may leave old values in place if they match new. User does not care whether the actual UI event happens.

@Basilevs I wouldn't have conditions in updateUI. I'd just set the UI to whatever state, and not care what it was before, and especially not care if that is a visual no-op

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@candied_orange, "Bob could ignore you completely." - I don't think any programmer reasonably expects the computer to ignore the programmer! That statement is too hardline. The issue here seems to be that the check (and potential no-op) is considered astonishing by the callers, rather than within the terms of what they would expect the call to do based on their broad understanding. If you call x.increment(), you don't reasonably expect there to be a hidden check where the increment silently fails if x = 42.

@Steve when I type x = ""; x.print(); I absolutely insist that the computer ignore me.

@candied_orange, that's a fair counter-example, but you get my point that callers expect methods to do certain things and not do other things. What those expectations are may vary in nature and in how specific they are, but callers expect the effect of a method to correspond to their understanding of what that method does - nobody expects a call to have consequences that are completely random or unknown.

@Steve random speaks to nondeterministic behavior which can be a very bad thing. But unknown behavior from the callers point of view can absolutely be a requirement. Stop insisting on knowing everything. Let something else deal with it.

@candied_orange, of course you don't have to know every single detail, but there is still an irreducible amount you must know about what each call does, in order to successfully design (or later readapt) the program for its purpose.

@steve insisting on knowing every detail of what’s going on all at the same level of abstraction is a procedural programming habit. Pushing details behind abstractions where you don’t have to think about them is more object oriented. It’s also less coupled. It is entirely possible to get the details the caller deals with down to simply “do it now”. No returns. No exceptions. Just do it now and leave me alone. The name for that level of coupling is “event”.

@candied_orange, but somebody has to understand what is going on, in order to perform the essential design work - in order to make basic decisions such as whether a method should even be called, or in what order. If every call is like "open Mystery Box X", the obvious question is why such a call is even necessary and how it came to exist in the program. It's not necessarily about knowing every detail - but there is still some kind of constraint, some kind of detail (which may differ from case to case), some kind of shared understanding with others, on which a developer must be able to rely.

@candied_orange your point would be even better communicated if you just post the last message from chat - "the natural language from method name does not establish postcondition contract". Because  you argue that methods can be configured to do nothing, I argue, that natural language communicates that method promises something and we are at impasse.

@Basilevs well hang on. Natural language certainly can promise something. I definitely would prefer names that did that over methods named after Simpsons characters. But reality and configuration can break that promise, even silently. That silence can be required. Communicating the promise well is a good thing. The problem is thinking you can rely on the promise despite everything else. No promise is that strong. When you understand that the "try" prefix feels redundant. Are we still at an impasse?

@candied_orange internally method can do whatever. But external observer should see expected result. If (observable) promise is broken, the method name is incorrect. Introduce a new method with new contract/promise and a different name.

@candied_orange remember LSP - similar principle applies. Any method implementation is allowed as long as it behaves to contract.

@Basilevs yes but configuration can replace contract. The null object pattern is proof. Yes client A needs service A to follow contract A. But then someone changes everything to be B’s that use the same interface with a different contract.

@Basilevs why is it a contract for logging can silently do nothing when so configured but nothing else can unless you put "try" in its name?

@candied_orange neither null object nor log interfaces have observable post-conditions for clients, so they are fine.

@Basilevs null object is meant to be swapped in for something that does have observable post-conditions. It's simply a special case where the observable post-condition is a whole lot of nothing.

@candied_orange that's my point - if no postconditions are observable, method can do  whatever it wants.

@Basilevs right, but you understand that every method has this special case right?

The method's job is to do something.
If that something is only done based on condition(s) known only to the method, then so be it.  The caller does not need to know or care about them.
If they did, then they would be testing the preconditions themselves ...
if( condition ) 
   doSomething(); 

... which makes for even messier code or passing the conditions as arguments to the method for evaluation there.
public void doSomething( bool condition ) 

(Incidentally, this approach would make the addition of conditions 2 and 3 clearer, because you'd need a new method for each).
It seems to me that the method is working just fine.
The problem is that the Developers aren't aware of these internal conditions.  The way to communicate such things to Developers is through the Documentation.

"The way to communicate such things to Developers is through the Documentation." -  everything sounded good up until this point.

You tend to find these naming and placement difficulties arise from a somewhat awkward conceptualisation in the first place, or from an unsound division of labour between the person who writes the method and the person who calls it, which leads to the callers using the method with an unsound understanding of what it does.
With these kind of methods which self-check, and which silently and unexpectedly become a no-op under certain circumstances, what it tends to imply is that a condition should be checked at the call site before the main call occurs and that the caller should be in charge of that check.
The reason there is a deviation from this pattern and there is an attempt to fold the check into the called method, is either because the check has to be made annoyingly frequently at different call sites, or because developers keep forgetting to make the check and the code runs incorrectly for that reason.
The problem is, having folded a silent check into the method, your developers are expressing surprise about the occasional no-op behaviour. That suggests they should be rehearsing the check themselves explicitly in code at the call site, because they (apparently) need to know that the check is occurring and are tending to forget that it does.
If the checking code is itself complicated, then there is nothing wrong with you providing that as a checking method separately from the main method, but the caller still has to go through the pattern of making the check then deciding whether to make the main call, and therefore cannot forget the possibility that the main call (and the work associated with it) does not occur.
If necessary, the check can be performed redundantly inside the method, throwing an invalid op if the call has occurred in the wrong circumstances.
However, if you stick with the existing code structure, then DoSomethingIfCondition is as good a name as any.

If the check always has to be done, there is no reason to burden clients with it.

@Basilevs, that's not true. The issue here seems to be that the client developers need to know that the specific check is being done or that the execution is conditional. The OP isn't clear why in this case, but it's basically a case of important but non-obvious details being nested too deeply in code.

Clients should not need to know that. The problem lies not with the method in question but with other related APIs . Probably some other ill-defined contract requires an action to be done, but fails to check if it was actually done or to do it itself, or to throw an informative exception.

@Basilevs, I agree, there is often another connected problem in these cases.

An appropriate name is
trySometing()

Method should inform client, that it does not guarantee the named side-effect, but it should not reveal any implementation details.
This pattern is usually associated with exception handling, but IMO it is useful without those too.

Thank you. But then pretty every method would have to be prefixed with "try". Does it worry you?

@SergeyZolotarev only the ones that have conditions

@Caleth hardly any method doesn't (or shouldn't) perform any checks at all (except for accessors, maybe)

This is not about conditions, it is about postconditions. When the postcondition is a potential noop, but the action implies a stronger postcondition in a natural language, we can modify the name with "try" prefix to soften the implied postcondition.

If a method is called for its (useful) side effect, and that side effect occurs conditionally (I'd still argue hardly anything is unconditional at all), then its name should be prefixed with "try". Did I understand you correctly?

@SergeyZolotarev my answer is trying to be more general than that, but your understanding is close enough.

It’s not appropriate. TryXxx means you always try to do xxx but it might fail sometimes. In this case the method of function will often deliberately not do xxx even if it was possible.

Here you use naming convention like
public void Profileverification();

or
public void UpdateSessionIfExpire();


public void CreateDirectoryIfNotExist();

public chekIfSessionExpire();

Or 

public void IsSessionExpire();

